# How do I get the position in a 2D Numpy array when iterating?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D Numpy array representing a level map in a tile-based game I'm making in Python`3.7`. My array is 50 rows x 50 columns, and each value is an integer number representing a sprite type (various wall parts, floors, etc). When I iterate through the array and find a wall sprite (for example), I want to know the row and column number of that value so I can reference it directly.

It seems such a simple thing, but I can't seem to find the right Numpy function that will iterate through the 2D array and return the *position*`[row, col]`of each one it finds. I can then calculate it's relative position on the screen using the array position, and then test collision with `.colliderect()`.

EDIT: For more clarity, I'm adding the fact that I need to compare each integer value in the array to a`List` of wall parts (also integers), and if it's in the list, return the array position.

**TL;DR** How do I iterate through a Numpy 2darray and return the`[row, col]` for each match instead of the value?

Comment: well, usually you would just use the boolean expression `array == 4` for example would give a `50x50` matrix with true or false, I think [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get indices if boolean array doesn't work for what ever you need. I couldn't possibly tell you how to use it though, numpy confuses the heck out of me :)

Comment: Consider using a list of lists instead.  The standard python `enumerate` gives index along with value.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.argwhere`.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((50, 50))
>>> a[3, 4] = 1
>>> a[4, 5] = 1
>>> for i, j in np.argwhere(a == 1): print(i, j)
... 
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
```

(The above example was run using python 2, hence the tuples in the output shown, but it is otherwise exactly the same in python 3.)

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with my program, but the problem now is that because I have many wall types, the `.argwhere` method doesn't like it when I write it like this: `for row, col in np.argwhere(level_map.data in level_map.WALL_TYPES):` Is it because I'm comparing it to a List (WALL_TYPES)?

Comment: It works if I use `.argwhere(level_map.data == 1)` but how would I apply this to a bunch of wall types? I get an error: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` but I'm not sure how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that you could use nested for-loops and a data structure like below:

let's say map is a 2-D numpy array and that 1 represents a wall type and 2 represents a floor type.

code:

```
locationsToSprites = dict()#Data structure that stores the locations of the sprite type. 
for row in range(0, len(map)): #looping through all rows
    for col in range(0, len(map[row])):#looping through all columns of a row
        if(map[row][col] == 1):
            locationsToSprites[(row, col)] = 'the wall type'
        elif(map[row][col] == 2):
            locationsToSprites[(row, col)] = 'the floor type'
```

Now, because a dictionary was used to store the locations of the sprites we can just print the keys of the dictionary to get all the locations.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I was originally used standard For loops, but when I heard Numpy arrays were faster to work with, I switched my List array to a Numpy array, and I'm now looking for a faster way to iterate using Numpy, but it's looking like standard iteration might be the way to go after all.